# Inheritance and Instances Java

Tags: java, oop, package

> On Java Packages: In a package where each class has its own .java file, is it possible to initialize a public Parent class object with a package-restricted child class object outside their
>   package? To-wit: Can I make a method in Parent that initializes itself
>   with the hidden child instance?
>
> I know "this. new Child()" works but only if child is an inner class.
>   I am trying to really practice proper object encapsulation so I want the child classes to remain hidden from anyone outside its package.
>
> Edit: To further clarify my question I've added initWithAnyChild() in Parent class and a child class ChildB().
>
> For Instance:

```
package righthere;//Parent.java



 public class Parent{

   public Parent(){}


   public void initWithChildA(){ this.new ChildA(); }

   public Parent initWithAnyChild(/*An identifier*/){

       switch(/*identifier*/){

         case /*ChildA*/: return new ChildA();
         case /*ChildB*/: return new ChildB();

         default: break;
        }

       return null;
    }
 }
```

/***/

```
package righthere;//ChildA.java

 class ChildA extends Parent{

     //Implementation;
  }
```

/***/

```
package righthere;//ChildB.java

 class ChildB extends Parent{

      //Implementation;


 }
```

/***/

```
package somewhere;//Test.java

import righthere.*;

public class Test{



   Parent var1.initWithChildA(); //Would not work since ChildA is not an inner class.

   Parent var2 = var2.initWithAnyChild(/*ChildA*/)//Would this work?



  }

 /*Is initWithAnyChild() the better way to go about this? Or is there 
  *an easier way?
  */
```

Comment: Are you trying to create an inner class?  `ChildA` would have to be inside the definition of `Parent`.

Comment: You can't get `new` to return anything besides the class you have named.  Would a factory method work?  That can return any valid return type.

Comment: @ScaryWombat Doesn't that go against some programming norms?

Comment: @markspace To your first question:No, each child class is in its own .java file but is package hidden. To your second: may be a factory method would work, but I'm trying to see if there's some way to use "new" or some simple form of initializing.

Comment: So you want `package-private` constructors?

Comment: The child constructors are already package-private as are the classes. I would like to be able to access their methods via inheritance in some other package using Parent variable. The problem was instantiating the public Parent variable with the package-private child class(who are in the same package), outside that package.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my question:

Using my example, the method in Parent class, "initWithAnyChild(/*An identifier*/)" works, where I can retrieve the package private sub-classes and store it in the public Parent class variable(Polymorphism) and be able to use it outside its package.

Maybe my question was too confusing to understand, or I wasn't clear enough? Apologies still, it's my first post here.